# How does Elasticsearch/Lucene achieve such performance when querying multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, full-text-search, compound-index

According to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617674/does-elasticsearch-have-compound-indexes), Elasticsearch doesn't seem to use compound indexes for querying multiple fields, and instead queries multiple indexes and then intersects the results.

My question is how does it achieve such high performance? Surely a composite index is faster since it leads you straight to the desired data, rather than querying multiple indexes, which in turn return more data, and then compare the results?

I get the advantages of the multiple indexes, regarding the field order, etc., but in terms of performance, surely it's inferior...